# MongoDB: How to count elements in array which is inside of two objects?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, object

I have a database of products in MongoDB. Inside main objects, there is another object "GL_related", and inside the "GL_related" object there is an array "also_viewed". How can I count the elements inside the "also_viewed" array of a specific object with the title "Sunglasses"(by using the aggregate pipeline method)?

The result should be "4".

Sample data:

```
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b6d1cd7367de7f58b4908"),
        "GL_asin" : "0456840532",
        "GL_title" : "Sunglasses",
        "GL_related" : {
            "also_viewed" : [ 
                "B001K9DPPC", 
                "B00BV9MU2K", 
                "B0042FHTDK", 
                "B003KK5LEW"
            ]
        }
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d0b6d1cd7367de7f58b4907"),
        "GL_asin" : "0456856293",
        "GL_title" : "T-Shirt",
        "GL_related" : {
            "also_viewed" : [ 
                "B005P1HF2U", 
                "B006K5JWOE"
            ]
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) combined with [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      itemCount: {
        $size: "$GL_related.also_viewed"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jXwqVlKicvH)

Comment: but if the database consists of more than one product, how do I filter so I get the result of "Sunglasses"?

Comment: You should use `$filter` to filter out the array first, if you provide proper structure it would be easier to answer.

Comment: I am new to MongoDB. You really helped me. I sorted it out. I used a `$match` instead of `$filter`with the `$project` you suggested and now I get the correct results. Thank You!